# How to avoid ice buildup in freezer?

Tags: kitchen

The title says it all. The question is not how to get rid of ice in the freezer, but how to avoid ice building up in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you open the freezer door, warm air enters which can hold a lot more moisture than cold air. When the air cools, the water vapour contained in it comes out as dew, which then freezes onto the interior surfaces.

You can't prevent that, but to minimise it

- Leave the freezer door open for the shortest possible time you can. If you get something out to remove a portion, close the door until you are ready to put it back.
- Wrap everthing you put in the freezer in a sealed plastic bag to prevent water vapour escaping. For example, I can buy frozen baked potatoes in a cardboard box: wrap them.
- Don't put 'wet' things in the freezer, for example an ice cube tray. Moisture will migrate onto the freezer surfaces. Put the ice cube tray inside another sealed container.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up. However, if you notice an inexplicable increase of ice buildup, a) check the door seal and replace it if it’s old or damaged and b) check the behavior of other people in your house, they may not be as diligent as they should be. One word: teenagers.

Answer (score 0):

Now and then you defrost the unit to get rid of the build up.

When you have all the ice gone:

- Dry the surface with an old towel.

Do one of the following.

- spray it with spray cooking oil
- Wipe the entire inside surface with old wrappers from butter or margarine.
- We have a rag that is saturated with a mix of oil and beeswax used to maintain our salad bowl.  Use this to wipe the inside surface.

This will not prevent ice from forming but it will delay it. and make it much easier to remove.